# Objective-C 101/ Beginner

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective-C and I was wondering in Java when you want to output a statement or variable or something the code for it would be `System.out.println("text");`

So, I was wondering what the similar code would be for Objective-C when I would like to output text or a variable or something of that sort.

I already searched online and it says us `NSLog` but that only logs it to the console and does not output it to the user i also tried `printf`. I cannot seem to find something that works.

Comment: Are you using iOS? Mac OS X? Something else?

Comment: i am using a Mac OS X

Comment: What do you mean printf didn't work? It works for everyone else.

Comment: maybe i am not using it correctly can you give me and example on how it is used

Comment: Can you define "output to user"? The console is the only output unless you're creating a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Using `printf`:

```
printf(@"%d", 4);
```

The above won't work.

It should be:

```
printf("%d", 4); //without the @
```

Output example:

```
NSLog(@"Hello!");
```

Output an object:

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello!";
NSLog("%@", myString);
```

Output a string constant:

```
NSLog(@"This is my %@", @"string");
```

Output a class name:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(NSObject));
```

Output an `NSError`:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
```

Output a float:

```
NSLog(@"%f", x);
```

To name a few. For further information, read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Hope this helps.

***Addendum (regarding "output to user"):***

If I understand you correctly, you would like to show some text on the screen?

By the way, in Java `System.out.println("text");` will just output to the console, not in the app, regardless if you are using OSX, Ubuntu, Windows or Gentoo....

There are numerous tutorials online, but let's hope this will get you started:

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){{0.0f, 0.0f}, 140.0f, 25.0f}];
myLabel.text = @"Hello World!";

[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

Comment: NSLog doesn't just "output an object". It prints a log statement including the program name, time stamp and the formatted string you specify to stderr. If you simply want to print something to stdout, all those NSLog examples should all be something like `printf("%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:YOUR NSLOG ARGS HERE] UTF8String])`.

Comment: @Chuck Yes, you're definitely correct. But since he tagged the question as objective-c, I simply show how one would do it with `NSLog`.

Answer (score 1):

To print out a string:

```
    NSLog(@"This is my string.");
```

*If you want to include variables in what you print out,* you can use the string in `NSLog()` as a formatter for variables that you list after the string:

```
    NSString *myString = @"my string";
    NSLog(@"This is %@", myString);

    //  OUTPUT: This is my string
```

`%@` is a placeholder for the **myString** variable. Other placeholders include: `%i` or `%d` for integers, `%f` for floats, and `%@` is also used for objects.

```
    int age = 2;
    float weight = 25.5f;
    NSLog(@"At the early age of %d, the child weighed %f lbs.", age, weight);

    //  OUTPUT: At the early age of 2, the child weighed 25.5 lbs.
```